# Is there a way to detect whether any element of a nested structure of observables has changed?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is there a single emitter that can fire if any observable element of viewModel.data() has changed, or do I need to loop through and subscribe to each of the independent observables?

```
data: ko.observable([
      {
        name: "Chart Position",
        fields: ko.observableArray([
          {name: "marginBottom", type: "percOrNumber", value: ko.observable(), valueType: ko.observable()},
          {name: "marginLeft", type: "percOrNumber", value: ko.observable(), valueType: ko.observable()},
          {name: "marginRight", type: "percOrNumber", value: ko.observable(), valueType: ko.observable()},
          {name: "marginTop", type: "percOrNumber", value: ko.observable(), valueType: ko.observable()}
        ])
      }
    ]),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a computed observable to "subscribe" to multiple observable at the same time.  Any observable that has its value accessed in the evaluation of the computed observable will become a dependency.

So, you can do something like:

```
ko.computed(function() {
    this.one();  //just accessing the value for a dependency
    this.two();  //doesn't matter if we actually use the value
    this.three();

    //run some code here or if you have a reference to this computed observable, then you can even do a manual subscription against it.
}, vm);
```

If you want to subscribe to all observables in some object graph, then an easy way to do it, is to use `ko.toJS`.  In your example, you might want to do:

```
ko.computed(function() {
   ko.toJS(vm.data);  //will create dependencies on all observables inside "data"

   //run some code
}, vm.data);
```